# Printing Towers of Hanoi (with steps and towers)

Tags: c++, recursion, console

So, I'm trying my hand at making a recursive function to solve the Towers of Hanoi.
I believe that I have the gist of the loop, and I'm able to print out what moved as well as a simple text graphic of the 3 towers.

Here is my code:
It includes a Tower class that I made to be able to print the three towers onto the console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Tower
{
private:
    string name;
    vector<string> contents;

public:
    Tower(string n)
    {
        this->name = n;
    }

    void setName(string n)
    {
        this->name = n;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    void setVectorSize(int size)
    {
        contents.resize(size);
    }

    void pushDisk(string val)
    {
        this->contents.push_back(val);
    }

    void popDisk()
    {
        this->contents.pop_back();
    }

    string printTower()
    {
        string output = "Tower " + this->name + ": ";

        for (string disk : contents)
        {
            output += disk + " ";
        }

        return output;
    }

    void clearContents()
    {
        contents.clear();
    }

};

void towersOfHanoi(int, Tower*, Tower*, Tower*);
string orderedTowers(Tower*, Tower*, Tower*);

int main()
{
    int diskNum;
    char ans;
    bool run = true;

    auto tower1 = new Tower("1");
    auto tower2 = new Tower("2");
    auto tower3 = new Tower("3");

    do
    {
        cout << "How many disks would you like to use (positive integers only): ";
        cin >> diskNum;
        while (diskNum < 1)
        {
            cout << "\nThe number of disks must be a positive integer.\n"
                << "How many disks would you like to use (positive integers only): ";
            cin >> diskNum;
        }

        cout << endl << pow(2, diskNum) - 1 << " moves are needed to solve for " << diskNum << "  disk(s).\n";

        //tower1->setVectorSize(diskNum);
        //tower2->setVectorSize(diskNum);
        //tower3->setVectorSize(diskNum);

        for (int i = diskNum; i > 0; i--)
        {
            string c = to_string(i);
            tower1->pushDisk(c);
        }

        cout << orderedTowers(tower1, tower2, tower3) << endl;

        system("pause");

        towersOfHanoi(diskNum, tower1, tower2, tower3);

        cout << "\nWould you like to run again (Y/N): ";
        cin >> ans;

        if (toupper(ans) == 'Y')
        {
            run = true;
            system("cls");

            tower1->clearContents();
            tower2->clearContents();
            tower3->clearContents();
        }

        else if (toupper(ans) == 'N')
        {
            run = false;
        }

    } while (run == true);

    return 0;
}

void towersOfHanoi(int disks, Tower* t1, Tower* t2, Tower* t3)
{
    if (disks != 0)
    {
        towersOfHanoi(disks - 1, t1, t3, t2);

        cout << "\nMove disk " << disks << " from tower " << t1->getName() << " to tower " << t2->getName() << endl;

        t1->popDisk();
        t2->pushDisk(to_string(disks));

        cout << orderedTowers(t1, t2, t3) << endl;

        system("pause");

        towersOfHanoi(disks - 1, t2, t1, t3);
    }
}

string orderedTowers(Tower* t1, Tower* t2, Tower* t3)
{
    string output;

    if (t1->getName() == "1")
        output += t1->printTower() + "\n";

    else if(t2->getName() == "1")
        output += t2->printTower() + "\n";

    else if (t3->getName() == "1")
        output += t3->printTower() + "\n";



    if (t1->getName() == "2")
        output += t1->printTower() + "\n";

    else if (t2->getName() == "2")
        output += t2->printTower() + "\n";

    else if (t3->getName() == "2")
        output += t3->printTower() + "\n";



    if (t1->getName() == "3")
        output += t1->printTower() + "\n";

    else if (t2->getName() == "3")
        output += t2->printTower() + "\n";

    else if (t3->getName() == "3")
        output += t3->printTower() + "\n";


    return output;
}
```

However, I'm running into a problem with the program actually solving the puzzle: there are times when I move the disk, the number of a certain disk will be decreased by one.

For example, output for 3 disks would be:

```
How many disks would you like to use (positive integers only): 3

7 moves are needed to solve for 3  disk(s).
Tower 1: 3 2 1
Tower 2:
Tower 3:

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 1 from tower 1 to tower 2
Tower 1: 3 2
Tower 2: 1
Tower 3:

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 2 from tower 1 to tower 3
Tower 1: 3
Tower 2: 1
Tower 3: 2

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 1 from tower 3 to tower 1
Tower 1: 3 1
Tower 2: 1
Tower 3:

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 3 from tower 1 to tower 2
Tower 1: 3
Tower 2: 1 3
Tower 3:

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 1 from tower 2 to tower 3
Tower 1: 3
Tower 2: 1
Tower 3: 1

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 2 from tower 2 to tower 1
Tower 1: 3 2
Tower 2:
Tower 3: 1

Press any key to continue . . .

Move disk 1 from tower 1 to tower 2
Tower 1: 3
Tower 2: 1
Tower 3: 1

Press any key to continue . . .
```

It does take the minimum amount of moves for the puzzle to be solved, but looking at the output, it clearly isn't.

Basically, my questions are, what is causing the changing of the disk numbers? Is there anything blatantly wrong that I missed? And also, is there any way to better optimize my code?

Also, this is an assignment for a class I'm taking. so tips and hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: This might be a good idea to [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically learning how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line, stepping into calls, and monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I've been using the debugger several times running the same lines over and over again. I see where it changes the number of the disk, which I assume is when it calls (disk - 1) but otherwise, I don't know how to change it without breaking the recursion calls.

Comment: Btw. for a power of 2, the `pow()` function is a not so lucky choice. (It's working with `double`s.) A cleaner alternative would be to use `1u << diskNum` instead. `<< 1` is equivalent to `* 2`. However, keep in mind that `unsigned` has a limited number of bits. `1u << 32` would overflow a 32 bit `unsigned` resulting in 0. On the other hand, limiting the input `diskNum` to 30 wouldn't hurt. Otherwise, this could yield a damn long "story" and might bore the user...

Comment: I believe you have to debug again. IMHO, you have to focus on `t1->popDisk(); t2->pushDisk(to_string(disks));`. I recommend to modify `popDisk()` that it returns the popped disk. With this modification, you may compare what is popped from `t1` and what you push to `t2`...

Comment: Alright, Ill try that next, thank you

Comment: Okay, I changed my `popDisk()` function to return a string which I now send to the console. While doing some debugging though, I did notice that after just 2 recursions, for some reason, the compiler seems to skip the first few lines for my `towersOfHaoni()` function, which gets my `disks` to be one less than it should be. However I fixed the numbering of the disks by  directly sending the popped disk from `t1->popDisk()` to a `string s = t1->popDisk()` and then doing `t2->pushDisk(s)` I'm now kind of stuck because I don't understand the reason for disks becoming `1` again

Comment: Somehow I figured out the issue, and for now the program is working fine. I switched all the instances of `t2` in the recursive `towersOfHanoi()` function to `t3` and it works great for 3 disks. I kept the calls and the tower switching within each call the same however.